# How to compile the dll back after decompile C# dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, decompiler, recompile

I use reflector to decompile a asp.net dll, after that I find the bug and fixed it, now I want to compile it back to a dll, then I can deploy, but it seems that I can't how can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices, either you use Reflector's addin [Filedisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx), which is free, or commercial ( and pricy) .net dissemblers such as [spices.net](http://www.9rays.net/Category/53-spices_net_suite.aspx) or [salamander decompiler](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/).

I used Filedisassembler; the quality of the decompiled code is very bad. The decompiler code cannot be recompiled.

I'm sure about the quality of commercial decompilers but I suspect that it would be much better.

Edit: To use Filedisassembler, go to Reflector, `View->Addins`, click `Add` and select the `Filedisassembler.dll`.

Comment: How to use it ? I downloaded it, but it is only a Dll file ?

Comment: You have to put that DLL in one folder, and then at tools->addin, select the dll as the addin, something like that. You can explore around

Answer (score 2):

If the fix is simple enough and you know IL, you are better of round tripping it using IL instead of a high-level language such as C# or VB.Net.

See search: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=ildasm+IL+round-tripping